# webpack - Error: Cannot find module 'webpack/lib/node/NodeTemplatePlugin'

Tags: webpack

I got this error when I do ng serve --open. I had latest node/npm and angular-cli, etc. This is the error.

node -v (v10.13.0) & npm (6.4.1)

What can be done to fix this issue?

```
ERROR in ./src/main.ts
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/index.js):
Error: Cannot find module 'webpack/lib/node/NodeTemplatePlugin'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:580:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:506:25)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\mic\angular\test7\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\resource_loader.js:16:28)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:688:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)

at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\mic\angular\test7\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:23:27)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:688:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
ERROR in ./src/polyfills.ts
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/index.js):
Error: Cannot find module 'webpack/lib/node/NodeTemplatePlugin'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:580:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:506:25)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\mic\angular\test7\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\resource_loader.js:16:28)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:688:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\mic\angular\test7\node_modules\@ngtools   \webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:23:27)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:688:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
```

Comment: Do you have webpack installed globally? If so, try adding it as a dev dependency to your project. This issue on GitHub explains: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2131

Answer (score -1):

I guess that I've had the same problem and I fixed it with this:

1. at first type this:

   ```
   npm i webpack -g
   ```
2. then type:

   ```
   npm link webpack --save-dev
   ```
3. at the end:

   ```
   ng serve
   ```